# Не отображается весь код страницы html через requests get

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить страницу с помощью *Python*. После метода `requests.get` применяю `text` к переменной, в итоге получаю не весь код *html* страницы (нету `div`, `class` и т.д.).

Из-за этого `beautiful-soup` не может найти через `div`/`class` нужное мне значение.Каким образом можно получить весь код страницы?

Comment: часть страницы может генерироваться путем js

Comment: то есть в таком случае без вариантов запарсить страницу?А если через selenium

Comment: через него можно

Answer (score 0):

Есть вероятность, что вы получаете **мобильную** версию сайта или версию сайта **для ботов**. Дабы избежать этого, нужно притвориться браузером. Для этого нужно зименить **заголовки** на заголовки браузеров *Chrome*/*Mozilla* и т.д. при парсинге.

Так же стоит снизить скорость запросов.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36"
}

r = requests.get('url', timeout=30, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Однако, если стоит какая-то "защита" на сайте, то это может не помочь.

Comment: Заголовки я итак использую,попробовал таймаут добавить тоже толку 0.Есть может какие варианты ещё?